# Adding parameters to aws lambda events using templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

How do I add a (path) parameter to lambda function events using cloud formation templates?

Strangely using:

```
DeleteItem:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /item/{id}
            Method: delete
            Request:
            Parameters:
              Paths:
                id: true
```

works using aws-sam-cli. However when I try to deploy using cloud formation it says that property Request is not defined. I got this request idea from [the serverless docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#request-parameters) but seems to only work locally. I can't find documentation on how to do this in templates so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Serverless Framework uses its own syntax, which is different from SAM (although *can* be compiled down to SAM or raw CloudFormation).

You can find the SAM specification [here](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api).

It's not explicit, but all you need to do is use the `{path-name}` syntax. Adding `Request`/`Parameters` is not required (or supported).

For example:

```
Ratings:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Handler: ratings.handler
    Runtime: python3.6
    Events:
      Api:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /ratings/{id}
          Method: get
```

Would give you the an event with:

`event.pathParameters.id == 'whatever-was-put-in-the-id-position'`

(A long example can be found here: https://github.com/1Strategy/redirect/blob/master/redirect.yaml)

Comment: Is there a way to specify query string parameters? I couldn't figure from the SAM docs.

Comment: @WaqasShah - you don't have to specify query string parameters (afaik you can't), they'll just be available under `event.queryStringParameters`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-api-gateway-request

Comment: @thomasmichaelwallace: Yes these are available but if I want to mark some query param as required like what i can do via console. Is there any way to define that in SAM template. Thanks!